# Изменить размер ImageView и отобразить в Bitmap

Tags: java, android

В разметке ниже имеется `ImageView qr`, который изначально имеет высоту 0, так как сначала пользователю показываются результаты некоторых расчетов.

При нажатии кнопки "сохранить" хочу изменить высоту `ImageView` на 150 dp.
Но почему-то она просто отсутствует в итоговом документе PFD, хотя если изначально в разметке задать ей нужную высоту:

```
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

то все отображается в итоговом документе как надо.

Фрагмент разметки

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ResultHEndToPDF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultsWH_FHend"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultsWH_FHendAlt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_alt_press"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/qrPH"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/qrph" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Код создания PDF

```
private File resultFile;

   private boolean saveBitMap(View drawView) {
    Date dateNow = new Date();
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat formatForDateNow = new 
    SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm dd.MM.yyyy");

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
    "/POLYHYDRO");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    ImageView qr = findViewById(R.id.qrPH);
    
    //ЗДЕСЬ МЕНЯЮ РАЗМЕР
    qr.getLayoutParams().height = 150;
    qr.requestLayout();
    
    
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    // определяем размер страницы
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo =
            new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(drawView.getWidth(), drawView.getHeight() + 300, 
    1).create();
    // получаем страницу, на котором будем генерировать контент
    PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
    // получаем холст (Canvas) страницы
    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(drawView);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    document.finishPage(page);
    String fileName = formatForDateNow.format(dateNow);
    File file = new File(dir, "POLYHYDRO диаметр по нач. напору " + fileName + ".pdf");
    resultFile = file;
    try {

        document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
        document.close();
        
        //Обратно меняю, чтобы все как изначально было
        qr.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        qr.requestLayout();
        
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка сохранения: что-то пошло не так", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Запоминаем старые значения цветов, чтобы присвоить их обратно после экспорта
    Resources resources = getResources();
    int oldTextColor = resources.getColor(R.color.text_color);
    int oldTextColorAlt = resources.getColor(R.color.text_color_alt_press);
    int oldBackgroundColor = resources.getColor(R.color.press_back);
    for (TextView textView : textList) textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (View views : listSeparator) views.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    /*for (TextView textView : textListAlt) textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);*/
    findViewById(R.id.strScrollHend).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null) {
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    view.draw(canvas);
    for (TextView textView : textList) textView.setTextColor(oldTextColor);
    for (TextView textView : textListAlt) textView.setTextColor(oldTextColorAlt);
    for (View views : listSeparator) views.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    findViewById(R.id.strScrollHend).setBackgroundColor(oldBackgroundColor);
    return returnedBitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил тем, что не изначально в представлении находится ImageView, а я его в методе saveBitMap просто создаю из ресурса и добавляю в Canvas в самый низ после прорисовки ResultHEndToPDF

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.qrph);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,(int)(drawView.getWidth()/2)-75,drawView.getHeight()+20,null);
```